# Особенности языка go

Tags: golang

Если поконкретней, то я сейчас разбираюсь с фреймворком revel и нашел кусок кода, который мне непонятен: http://pastebin.com/ce5M9Mfn. Конкретно меня беспокоят первые две строки функции - у них странный синтаксис. Первая часть (буква с) это... назову это объектом, понятно. Следующая часть - видимо, какой-то пакет, входящий в "controllers". Потом идет функция, которая что-то делает. Но что после неё? ещё одна функция?

```
    package controllers

import (
        "github.com/robfig/revel"
        "revel/app/models"
)
......

func (c Application) Hello(myName string) revel.Result {
        c.Validation.MinSize(myName, 3).Message("Your name is not long enough!")
        c.Validation.Required(myName).Message("Your name is required!")
        if c.Validation.HasErrors() {
                c.Validation.Keep()
                c.FlashParams()
                return c.Redirect(Application.Index)
        }
        return c.Render(myName)
}
```

Comment: В pastebin пусто, вставьте код сюда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что Вы видите, это [Method declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations).

Разбор по кускам

```
func - это ключевое слово, куда же без него.
(c Application) это "Receiver" - получатель.
Hello - а это уже имя метода
(myName string) и его параметры
revel.Result и тип.
```

если я правильно понимаю go, то `Receiver` - это то, что в других языках называется `this`, `self`.

Comment: Нет, это понятно. Мне неясны строки чуть пониже, вот эти:

        c.Validation.MinSize(myName, 3).Message("Your name is not long enough!")
        c.Validation.Required(myName).Message("Your name is required!")

Вот про них я и говорил.

Comment: ничего удивительно не вижу в них. строку 

    c.Validation.MinSize(myName, 3).Message("Your name is not long enough!")

можно переписать как

    x1 := c.Validation
    x2 := x1.MinSize(myName, 3)
    x2.Message("Your name is not long enough!")

Обычная конструкция для многих языков. c.Validation возвращает некий объект. у него вызывается свой метод, который опять же возвращает объект. Типы `x1` и `x2` ещё нужно уточнить.

Comment: спасибо, теперь всё понятно.